Updating dependent state in Zustand and TS
I have a many-to-many relationship between Users and files in my application. I am using Zustand for state management in the frontend. I am using MongodDB and Nest.js in the backend.
When I try to delete a file, the corresponding id in the user must also be deleted. The backend is able to perform that perfectly. But I am having a hard time implementing that in the frontend.
# Store.ts

export type StoreType = UserType & FileType

const UseGlobalStoreBase = create<StoreType>()(
  devtools(
    (...args) => ({
      ...usersSlice(...args),
      ...filesSlice(...args),
    }),
    {
      enabled: true
    },
  ),
);

# UserType.ts

type UserModelType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  textFiles: FileType[];
  exeFiles: FileType[];
  docFiles: FileType[];
};

export interface UserType {
  users: UserModelType;
  setUsers: () => Promise<void>;
  addUser: (data: Partial<UserModelType>) => Promise<void>;
  editUser: (userId: string, data: Partial<UserModelType>) => Promise<void>;
  deleteUser: (userId: string) => Promise<void>;
}

# FileType.ts

type FileModelType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  extension: string;
  owners: UserType[];
};

export interface FileType {
  files: FileModelType[];
  setFiles: () => Promise<void>;
  addFile: (data: Partial<FileModelType>) => Promise<void>;
  editFile: (fileid: string, data: Partial<FileModelType>) => Promise<void>;
  deleteFile: (fileid: string) => Promise<void>;
}

# FileActions.ts

export const DeleteFile = async (id: string, extension: "textFiles" | "exeFiles" | "docFiles"): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await DeleteFileApi(id);

    UseGlobalStore.setState(
      produce((state: StoreType) => {
        const ownerIds =
          state.files.find((ie) => ie.id === id)?.owners ?? [];

        state.files =
          state.files.filter((ie: FileModelType) => ie.id !== id);

        ######################################
        # Approach 1
        ######################################
      }),

      ######################################
      # Approach 2
      ######################################
      }),
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error deleting initiating event:", error);
  }
};

How do I update the users slice to remove the deleted file from the corresponding owners in the state in zustand. I have tried updating the state like below separately, but the issue is that my key which is the extension of the file is dynamic and when I try to use [key] syntax, Zustand/TS throws an error saying "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'StoreType'"
# Using separate setState to update the users - Approach 1
UseGlobalStore.setState((state) => ({
  user: state.user[extension].filter((fileId: string) => fileId !== id),
}));

or
# Updating the users in the same setState - Approach 2
state.user[extension] = state.user[extension].filter((fileId: string) => fileId !== id)

